# How can I make this MySQL Query faster

Tags: mysql

Below I have probably the biggest single MySQL query I have ever written.  As expected it seems to take a pretty hefty toll on the MySQL server when I run it.  Or even worse, multiple of it running at once.

Everything i did in the query I did out of what I believed to be necessity to get the results I need with the table structure that already exists.

So My question is this:
Can you see any obvious changes I could make to this query to improve performance?
Any steps I took that aren't needed?
Any DB changes/tweeks, indexs, ect. I could do to make this an easier load on the server?

I open myself to the internet of criticism please be kind, or at least constructive I'm new. :)

```js
SELECT td.Area,
sum(COALESCE(se.ErectionFootage,0)) AS CountErectionFootage, sum(COALESCE(sb.BoltUpCount,0)) AS CountBoltUp, sum(COALESCE(sw.WeldCount,0)) AS CountWeld, sum(COALESCE(st.TrimActivitiesCount,0)) AS CountTrimActivities, sum(COALESCE(sm.MiscActivitiesCount,0)) AS CountMiscActivities, sum(COALESCE(ssu.SupportCount,0)) AS CountSupports,
(sum(COALESCE(sb.BoltUpCount, 0)) + sum(COALESCE(sw.WeldCount, 0))) AS CountBasicConnection,
(sum(COALESCE(st.TrimActivitiesCount, 0)) + sum(COALESCE(sm.MiscActivitiesCount, 0)) + sum(COALESCE(ssu.SupportCount, 0))) AS CountBasicTrimActivities,

sum(COALESCE(se.ErectionHours,0)) AS HoursErection, sum(COALESCE(sb.BoltUpHours,0)) AS HoursBoltUp, sum(COALESCE(sw.WeldHours,0)) AS HoursWeld, sum(COALESCE(st.TrimHours,0)) AS HoursTrim, sum(COALESCE(sm.MiscHours,0)) AS HoursMisc, sum(COALESCE(ssu.SupportHours,0)) AS HoursSupports,
(sum(COALESCE(sb.BoltUpHours, 0)) + sum(COALESCE(sw.WeldHours, 0))) AS HoursBasicConnection,
(sum(COALESCE(st.TrimHours, 0)) + sum(COALESCE(sm.MiscHours, 0)) + sum(COALESCE(ssu.SupportHours, 0))) AS HoursBasicTrimActivities,

sum(COALESCE(er.InstalledFootage,0)) AS InstalledFootage, sum(COALESCE(er.InstalledBoltUps,0)) AS InstalledBoltUps, sum(COALESCE(er.InstalledWelds,0)) AS InstalledWelds,
sum(COALESCE(er.InstalledBasicConnections,0)) AS InstalledBasicConnections, 

sum(COALESCE(er.InstalledTrim,0)) AS InstalledTrim, sum(COALESCE(er.InstalledMisc,0)) AS InstalledMisc, sum(COALESCE(er.InstalledSupports,0)) AS InstalledSupports,
sum(COALESCE(er.InstalledBasicTrim,0)) AS InstalledBasicTrim,

TRUNCATE(sum(COALESCE(er.EarnedErectionHours,0)),2) AS EarnedErectionHours, 
TRUNCATE(sum(COALESCE(er.EarnedBoltUpHours, 0)),2) AS EarnedBoltUpHours,
TRUNCATE(sum(COALESCE(er.EarnedWeldHours,0)),2) AS EarnedWeldHours,
TRUNCATE(sum(COALESCE(er.EarnedTrimHours,0)),2) AS EarnedTrimHours,
TRUNCATE(sum(COALESCE(er.EarnedSupportHours,0)),2) AS EarnedSupportHours,
TRUNCATE(sum(COALESCE(er.EarnedMiscHours,0)),2) AS EarnedMiscHours,

TRUNCATE((sum(COALESCE(er.EarnedBoltUpHours, 0)) + sum(COALESCE(er.EarnedWeldHours,0))),2) AS EarnedBasicConnectHours,
TRUNCATE((sum(COALESCE(er.EarnedTrimHours, 0)) + sum(COALESCE(er.EarnedMiscHours,0)) + + sum(COALESCE(er.EarnedSupportHours,0))),2)AS EarnedBasicTrimHours,

(sum(COALESCE(se.ErectionFootage,0)) - sum(COALESCE(er.InstalledFootage,0))) AS RemainingFootage,
(sum(COALESCE(sb.BoltUpCount,0)) - sum(COALESCE(er.InstalledBoltUps,0))) AS RemainingBoltUps,
(sum(COALESCE(sw.WeldCount,0)) - sum(COALESCE(er.InstalledWelds,0))) AS RemainingWelds, 
((sum(COALESCE(sb.BoltUpCount,0)) + sum(COALESCE(sw.WeldCount,0))) - (sum(COALESCE(er.InstalledBoltUps,0)) + sum(COALESCE(er.InstalledWelds,0)))) AS RemainingBasicConnections, 

(sum(COALESCE(st.TrimActivitiesCount,0)) - sum(COALESCE(er.InstalledTrim,0))) AS RemainingTrimActivities,
(sum(COALESCE(ssu.SupportCount,0)) - sum(COALESCE(er.InstalledSupports,0))) AS RemainingSupports,
(sum(COALESCE(sm.MiscActivitiesCount,0)) - sum(COALESCE(er.InstalledMisc,0))) As RemainingMiscActivities,
((sum(COALESCE(st.TrimActivitiesCount,0)) + sum(COALESCE(sm.MiscActivitiesCount,0)) + sum(COALESCE(ssu.SupportCount,0))) - (sum(COALESCE(er.InstalledTrim,0)) +sum(COALESCE(er.InstalledMisc,0)) + sum(COALESCE(er.InstalledSupports,0)))) AS RemainingBasicTrimActivities,

TRUNCATE((sum(COALESCE(se.ErectionHours,0)) - sum(COALESCE(er.EarnedErectionHours,0))), 2) AS RemainingErectionHours,
TRUNCATE((sum(COALESCE(sb.BoltUpHours,0)) - sum(COALESCE(er.EarnedBoltUpHours,0))),2) AS RemainingBoltUpHours,
TRUNCATE((sum(COALESCE(sw.WeldHours,0)) - sum(COALESCE(er.EarnedWeldHours,0))),2) AS RemainingWeldHours, 
TRUNCATE(((sum(COALESCE(sb.BoltUpHours,0)) + sum(COALESCE(sw.WeldHours,0))) - (sum(COALESCE(er.EarnedBoltUpHours,0)) + sum(COALESCE(er.EarnedWeldHours,0)))),2) AS RemainingBasicConnectionHours, 

TRUNCATE((sum(COALESCE(st.TrimHours,0)) - sum(COALESCE(er.EarnedTrimHours,0))),2) AS RemainingTrimHours,
TRUNCATE((sum(COALESCE(ssu.SupportHours,0)) - sum(COALESCE(er.EarnedSupportHours,0))),2) AS RemainingSupportHours,
TRUNCATE((sum(COALESCE(sm.MiscHours,0)) - sum(COALESCE(er.EarnedMiscHours,0))),2) As RemainingMiscHours,
TRUNCATE(((sum(COALESCE(st.TrimHours,0)) + sum(COALESCE(sm.MiscHours,0)) + sum(COALESCE(ssu.SupportHours,0))) - (sum(COALESCE(er.EarnedTrimHours,0)) +sum(COALESCE(er.EarnedMiscHours,0)) + sum(COALESCE(er.EarnedSupportHours,0)))),2) AS RemainingBasicTrimHours
,sum(COALESCE(tq.HydroHours, 0)) AS HoursHydro



FROM trackerDetails td
 JOIN trackerQuantities tq
  ON tq.ID = td.ID
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT tq.ID, ss.PSAActivityID, at.ActivityType, 
TRUNCATE(sum(COALESCE((tq.EstimatedHours/tq.TakeOffQuantity*(se.ErectionLengthSpool1 + se.ErectionLengthSpool2 + se.ErectionLengthSpool3 + se.ErectionLengthSpool4 + se.ErectionLengthSpool5 + se.ErectionLengthSpool6)),0)),2) AS EarnedErectionHours,
TRUNCATE(sum(COALESCE((tq.EstimatedHours/tq.TakeOffQuantity*sb.BoltUpInstalled), 0)),2) AS EarnedBoltUpHours,
TRUNCATE(sum(COALESCE((tq.EstimatedHours/tq.TakeOffQuantity*sw.WeldInstalled),0)),2) AS EarnedWeldHours,
TRUNCATE(sum(COALESCE((tq.EstimatedHours/tq.TakeOffQuantity*TrimInstalled),0)),2) AS EarnedTrimHours,
TRUNCATE(sum(COALESCE((tq.EstimatedHours/tq.TakeOffQuantity*SupportInstalled),0)),2) AS EarnedSupportHours,
TRUNCATE(sum(COALESCE((tq.EstimatedHours/tq.TakeOffQuantity*MiscInstalled),0)),2) AS EarnedMiscHours,

sum(COALESCE((se.ErectionLengthSpool1 + se.ErectionLengthSpool2 + se.ErectionLengthSpool3 + se.ErectionLengthSpool4 + se.ErectionLengthSpool5 + se.ErectionLengthSpool6),0)) AS InstalledFootage,

sum(COALESCE(sb.BoltUpInstalled,0)) AS InstalledBoltUps, 
sum(COALESCE(sw.WeldInstalled,0)) AS InstalledWelds,
(sum(COALESCE(sb.BoltUpInstalled,0)) + sum(COALESCE(sw.WeldInstalled,0))) AS InstalledBasicConnections, 

sum(COALESCE(st.TrimInstalled,0)) AS InstalledTrim,
sum(COALESCE(sm.MiscInstalled,0)) AS InstalledMisc,
sum(COALESCE(ssu.SupportInstalled,0)) AS InstalledSupports,
(sum(COALESCE(st.TrimInstalled,0)) + sum(COALESCE(sm.MiscInstalled,0)) + sum(COALESCE(ssu.SupportInstalled,0))) AS InstalledBasicTrim

FROM SubmissionStatus ss
 JOIN PSA.REF_ActivityTypes at
  ON at.ID = ss.ActivityType
         
 JOIN SubsDetails sd
  ON sd.SubmissionID = fk_SubmissionId
        
 LEFT JOIN SubsErection se
  ON se.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType = 11
 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT sb.ID, 1 AS BoltUpInstalled
    FROM SubsBoltUp sb) sb
  ON sb.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType = 21
        
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT sw.ID, 1 AS WeldInstalled
    FROM SubsWeld sw) sw
  ON sw.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType = 22

    LEFT JOIN (SELECT st.ID, st.TrimQuantity AS TrimInstalled
    FROM SubsTrim st) st
  ON st.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType = 31  
        
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT ssu.ID, 1 AS SupportInstalled
    FROM SubsSupports ssu) ssu
  ON ssu.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType = 32        
        
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT sm.ID, 1 AS MiscInstalled
    FROM SubsMisc sm) sm
  ON sm.ID = ss.ActivityRowId AND ss.ActivityType = 91


 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT tq.ID, tq.TakeOffQuantity, tq.EstimatedHours 
    FROM trackerQuantities tq) tq
  ON tq.ID = ss.fk_BidIDAssigned
        
WHERE fk_ActivityStatus IN (5)
GROUP BY tq.ID) er
  ON er.ID = td.ID
    
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT tq.ID, tq.TakeOffQuantity AS  ErectionFootage, tq.EstimatedHours AS ErectionHours
    FROM trackerQuantities tq
     JOIN trackerDetails td
      ON td.ID = tq.ID
    WHERE PipingActivityType = 'PE') se
  ON se.ID = td.ID

 LEFT JOIN (SELECT tq.ID, tq.TakeOffQuantity AS  BoltUpCount, tq.EstimatedHours AS BoltUpHours
    FROM trackerQuantities tq
     JOIN trackerDetails td
      ON td.ID = tq.ID
    WHERE PipingActivityType = 'BU') sb
  ON sb.ID = td.ID
        
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT tq.ID, tq.TakeOffQuantity AS  WeldCount, tq.EstimatedHours AS WeldHours
    FROM trackerQuantities tq
     JOIN trackerDetails td
      ON td.ID = tq.ID
    WHERE ECT = 'C' AND PipingActivityType != 'BU') sw
  ON sw.ID = td.ID
        
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT tq.ID,  tq.TakeOffQuantity AS  TrimActivitiesCount, tq.EstimatedHours AS TrimHours
    FROM trackerQuantities tq
     JOIN trackerDetails td
      ON td.ID = tq.ID
    WHERE ECT = 'T' AND PipingActivityType != 'MISC') st
  ON st.ID = td.ID

 LEFT JOIN (SELECT tq.ID, tq.TakeOffQuantity AS  SupportCount, tq.EstimatedHours AS SupportHours
    FROM trackerQuantities tq
     JOIN trackerDetails td
      ON td.ID = tq.ID
    WHERE PipingActivityType = 'S') ssu
  ON ssu.ID = td.ID
        
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT tq.ID, tq.TakeOffQuantity AS  MiscActivitiesCount, tq.EstimatedHours AS MiscHours
    FROM trackerQuantities tq
     JOIN trackerDetails td
      ON td.ID = tq.ID
    WHERE PipingActivityType = 'MISC') sm
  ON sm.ID = td.ID
        
GROUP BY td.Area

ORDER BY td.Area
```

**UPDATE:**
As requested (and a good request at that) Here is the Output from EXPLAIN

```js
# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
1, PRIMARY, td, index, PRIMARY,Area, Area, 138, , 65286, Using index
1, PRIMARY, tq, eq_ref, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 4, Job1111.td.ID, 1, 
1, PRIMARY, <derived2>, ref, <auto_key0>, <auto_key0>, 5, Job1111.td.ID, 1326, 
1, PRIMARY, <derived9>, ref, <auto_key0>, <auto_key0>, 4, Job1111.td.ID, 10, 
1, PRIMARY, <derived10>, ref, <auto_key0>, <auto_key0>, 4, Job1111.td.ID, 10, 
1, PRIMARY, <derived11>, ref, <auto_key0>, <auto_key0>, 4, Job1111.td.ID, 10, 
1, PRIMARY, <derived12>, ref, <auto_key0>, <auto_key0>, 4, Job1111.td.ID, 10, 
1, PRIMARY, <derived13>, ref, <auto_key0>, <auto_key0>, 4, Job1111.td.ID, 10, 
1, PRIMARY, <derived14>, ref, <auto_key0>, <auto_key0>, 4, Job1111.td.ID, 10, 
14, DERIVED, td, ALL, PRIMARY, , , , 65286, Using where
14, DERIVED, tq, eq_ref, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 4, Job1111.td.ID, 1, 
13, DERIVED, td, ALL, PRIMARY, , , , 65286, Using where
13, DERIVED, tq, eq_ref, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 4, Job1111.td.ID, 1, 
12, DERIVED, td, ALL, PRIMARY, , , , 65286, Using where
12, DERIVED, tq, eq_ref, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 4, Job1111.td.ID, 1, 
11, DERIVED, td, ALL, PRIMARY, , , , 65286, Using where
11, DERIVED, tq, eq_ref, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 4, Job1111.td.ID, 1, 
10, DERIVED, td, ALL, PRIMARY, , , , 65286, Using where
10, DERIVED, tq, eq_ref, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 4, Job1111.td.ID, 1, 
9, DERIVED, td, ALL, PRIMARY, , , , 65286, Using where
9, DERIVED, tq, eq_ref, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 4, Job1111.td.ID, 1, 
2, DERIVED, ss, ref, fk_StatusSubmissionId_idx,fk_tblSubmissionStatus_tblActivityStatuses_idx, fk_tblSubmissionStatus_tblActivityStatuses_idx, 5, const, 10, Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2, DERIVED, at, eq_ref, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 4, Job1111.ss.ActivityType, 1, Using where
2, DERIVED, sd, eq_ref, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 4, Job1111.ss.fk_SubmissionId, 1, Using index
2, DERIVED, se, ALL, PRIMARY, , , , 6, Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
2, DERIVED, <derived3>, ALL, , , , , 10, Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
2, DERIVED, <derived4>, ALL, , , , , 12, Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
2, DERIVED, <derived5>, ALL, , , , , 8, Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
2, DERIVED, <derived6>, ALL, , , , , 3, Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
2, DERIVED, <derived7>, ALL, , , , , 2, Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
2, DERIVED, <derived8>, ref, <auto_key0>, <auto_key0>, 4, Job1111.ss.fk_BidIDAssigned, 668, 
8, DERIVED, tq, ALL, , , , , 66824, 
7, DERIVED, sm, index, , fk_MiscSubmissionId_idx, 4, , 1, Using index
6, DERIVED, ssu, index, , SubmissionId_idx, 4, , 3, Using index
5, DERIVED, st, ALL, , , , , 8, 
4, DERIVED, sw, index, , fk_WeldSubmssionId_idx, 4, , 12, Using index
3, DERIVED, sb, index, , fk_BoltUpSubmissionId_idx, 4, , 10, Using index
```

Comment: If your JOIN columns and the columns in GROUP BY and ORDER BY are indexed there is little you can do IMO.Too many calculations,you should do it in your app or store some of the calculations in a column for fast access.

Comment: UPDATE:   First thing I did was I just added an index for td.Area.  That alone cut the query time for running 4 of these simultaneously from 11.4s down to 5.54s.

Comment: Put an EXPLAIN before this query and edit your question with the results

Comment: Perhaps you could consider doing this in multiple passes.  All those functions at once must be killing your server.  I would suggest creating temp tables for sections of it, then run one thing to union the results.